# How to find the occurrences and location of characters in command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm new to command line arguments, but I have to find the occurrences and locations of a multiple word string. Say I enter in:

```
good dog
```

I would enter in o on the command line to get three counts of o and the locations. However, what I have is:

```
Frequency of d = 0
Location of d = -13280
```

How do I find the locations and how do I parse the parameters?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, frequency;
    int *p;
    p=&argc;

    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if(argv[i]==argv[i])
        {
            frequency++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nFrequency of %c = %d\n", argv[2][0], frequency);
    printf("\nLocation of %c = %d\n", argv[2][0], p);
}
```

Comment: As I understood, you are passing your multiple word string as a command line arguments, right? And do you need to find the number of occurrences of all characters or just one that you specify? What do you mean by location: the address of the character or the position in the string from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be slightly confused about how input through main works. Basically, your idea of using command line parameters is pretty bad because you want to both specify the strings to be parsed but also which character to look for, which is pretty easy to mess up.

A better way is using something like scanf with a printf preceding it to request input both for the strings to be parsed and the character to look for. This then enforces an order so it's much more difficult to mess up.

Now, if you don't want to do that you still have to fix how you use argv. argv[0] contains the name of the program, not the first command line parameter. Statically referring to argv[2] isn't even really guaranteed to mean anything useful: it could be a part of the string you want to parse, or it could be the character you're looking for.

Secondly, when you pass command line parameters into the program, they will automatically be divided by spaces. That is, `good dog` will turn into two separate argv indexes: `good` will be argv[1] and `dog` will be argv[2] in this case. If you want to send them as one argument, you can type `"good dog"` to achieve that.

Here's a fully compilable program that is more of a sketch of what you probably want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0, frequency = 0; // wasn't initialized
    char DesiredChar = 'o';
    int  FirstLocationOfDesiredChar = -1;
    if (argc >= 1) {
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            int StringLength = strlen(argv[i]);
            for (; j < StringLength; j++) {
                if (argv[i][j] == DesiredChar) {
                    frequency++;
                    if (FirstLocationOfDesiredChar == -1) {
                        FirstLocationOfDesiredChar = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("Invalid no of inputs\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    printf("%d, %d", frequency, FirstLocationOfDesiredChar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much on the argv[] indexes. That particularly came in handy, as those were the indexes I didn't understand.